# Backbone.js: just one line to set local storage?

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

demo fiddle (with problem) http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/UJ4HN/19/

I have a collection defined like this

```
var Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Friend,

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("friends-list")
});
```

As far as I'm aware, that's all I need to do to get local storage to work (in addition to including it below backbone.js)

One thing I wasn't sure about, does the name "friends-list" have to correspond to a DOM element? I'm trying to save the "friends-list" so I called it that in local storage, however, localstorage doesn't seem to require passing a class or an id.

Here's a fiddle where you can see what I'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/UJ4HN/19/

On my local site, I'm adding a couple friends, refreshing the page, but the friends are not re-appearing.

**Update**

I've also done the following in my code on my local site

```
console.log(Backbone.LocalStorage);
```

and it's not throwing an error.

My attempt to debug

I tried this code (taken from another SO answer) in the window.AppView but nothing came up in the console.

```
this.collection.fetch({}, {
    success: function (model, response) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
        console.log("error");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage):

> Quite simply a localStorage adapter for Backbone. It's a drop-in replacement for Backbone.Sync() to handle saving to a localStorage database.

This LocalStorage plugin is just a replacement for Backbone.Sync so you still have to [`save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) your models and [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) your collections.

Since you're not saving anything, you never put anything into your LocalStorage database. You need to save your models:

```
showPrompt: function() {
    var friend_name = prompt("Who is your friend?");
    var friend_model = new Friend({
        name: friend_name
    });
    //Add a new friend model to our friend collection
    this.collection.add(friend_model);
    friend_model.save(); // <------------- This is sort of important.
},
```

You might want to use the `success` and `error` callbacks on that `friend_model.save()` too.

Since you're not `fetch`ing anything, you don't initialize your collection with whatever is in your LocalStorage database. You need to call `fetch` on your collection and you probably want to bind `render` to its `"reset"` event:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'showPrompt');
    this.collection = new Friends();
    this.collection.bind('add', this.render);
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch();
},
```

You'll also need to update your `render` to be able to render the whole collection:

```
render: function() {
    var $list = this.$('#friends-list');
    $list.empty();
    this.collection.each(function(m) {
        var newFriend = new FriendView({ model: m });
        $list.append(newFriend.render().el);
    });
    $list.sortable();
    return this; 
}
```

You could make this better by moving the "add one model's view" logic to a separate method and bind that method to the collection's `"add"` event.

And a stripped down and fixed up version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/haE9K/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I copied and pasted your code into my local host. There's one small problem that doesn't show on the fiddle. When I refresh the page, all the friends disappear. However, if I add a new friend, then all the friends are retrieved from localhost with the new friend added at the bottom. If I refresh the page again again,they all disappear, only to reappear if I add a new friend. Do you know why that's happening? Thanks in advance if you have time to explain.  However, in this demo app http://hiree.amberfeng.com/ I'm trying to learn from, they don't disappear on page refresh

Comment: @user1647484: Sounds like you're not rendering the view when you initialize things. What's different between the fiddle and your code?

Comment: my code is exactly the same as the fiddle. I copied and pasted the code from the fiddle into my editor, and I made sure the libraries are the same version.

Comment: Have you tried using the `success` and `error` callbacks on the `fetch` to see what's going on?

Comment: I updated the OP with the success/error callbacks I tried, but nothing showed in the console.

Comment: `fetch` should just have an `options` argument: `c.fetch({ success: ... })`.

Comment: it's logging "success" but the same problem exists

Comment: Does it `fetch` end up calling `render`?

Comment: I have no idea. Console's not telling me. I added this.render(); to the initializer after fetch() and same result. Unfortunately I'm not that good with console.

Comment: I got it to work eventually, but only by adding an "addAll" method which did essentially what you recommended in 'render,' namely, collection.each. However, I think your code might not have worked because you do collection.add, when it should be collection.create, which triggers the save to local storage for a collection. save only works for models.